# How can I lock the size of the html body?

Tags: html

I've been trying to lock the size of the body tag in html to make it more tidy. I had used many kinds of method such as:

- `<body style="height: 1450px; width: 1450px">`
- `<style type="text/css">
    body {style: height="1450px; width="1450px"}
   </style>`
- etc.

However none of these work. The text always expands the `<body>` so that it makes the background-image does not fit the size of the it. I even tried to use
`<img>` tag to control the image but it doesn't seems to work. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't know how to use...

Comment: please add all of your HTML to this so I can better see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would set a div that you can define your height and width

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
<style> 
  #wrapper{ width: 1450px; height: 1450px; margin: 0px auto;}
</style>
```

Comment: You can overwrite the max width when there's enough content inside of this.

Comment: Also, this will result in being overlapped on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Tester</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   div{z-index: -1}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body style="height: 1450px; width: 1450px">
  <div style="position: fixed; top: 0%; right: 0%"><img src="your background photo's path" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
  <p>This maybe work.</p>
 </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: [Hope that helps](I want to say that u are yummy)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need this :

```
html, body {
position: relative;
min-width: 1450px;
min-height: 1450px;
height: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can understand what happens here with body tag.

```css
body{
//width:40px;
//height:40px
max-width: 35px;
max-height: 35px;
min-width: 30px;
min-height: 30px;
background-color:grey;
}

div{
//width:50px;
//height:50px
max-width: 40px;
max-height: 50px;
min-width: 40px;
min-height: 50px;  
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<body> 
 
    <div>
    </div>
  
</body>
```

Note: The value of the min-height property overrides both max-height and height.